# App closes when the back button is pressed in ionic 5 android while the modal is opened

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

The app closes unexpectedly in ionic.
i'm using ionic v-5 and codova v-10.
i was trying to close the modal when the android hardware back button is pressed, but the app closes completely unexpectedly instead. i tried with the surfing the ionic forums for cordova the solution there dint worked for me.

i tried this piece of code in both app component and the modal component

```
 this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
      console.log('angular Handler was called!');
      this.modal.dismiss();
    });
```

and

```
 this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {    
        console.log("back button pressed")
        if(this.modal.top())
        {
          this.modal.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Even though trying these both code it didn't worked still the app was closed when the back button is pressed.
I'm trying this from very long time but not able find the solution!

Comment: I had the same issue with my app running on top of Capacitor and I solved it updating Capacitor dependencies such as: "@capacitor/app" , "@capacitor/core", "@capacitor/android", "@capacitor/cli". Maybe you should update your Cordova packages too.

Answer (score 0):

put this code inside function **initializeBackButtonCustomHandler()**

and call function inside **initializeApp()** this function

```
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, async () => {
      this.alert.dismissLoading();
      try {
        const element = await this.modalCtrl.getTop();
        if (element) {
          element.dismiss();
          return;
        }
      } catch (error) {
      }
});
```

Comment: is it in app component of modal component?